# IIF to Case statement

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, case, iif

I have the below code in Access which I'm migrating to SQL Server,

```
 IIf([code] Is Not Null,IIf([code]<>'ABC',

 IIf([length] Is Null,1,IIf([Length]=0,1,

 IIf([width] Is Null,1,IIf([Width]=0,1,

 IIf([height] Is Null,1,IIf([Height]=0,1,

 0))))))))
```

I believe it checks for code not null and not equal to 'ABC' then length should be null or 0 then it assigns a value 1 of the condition fails then it is 0. I need a little help with writing it with case.

Comment: Code syntax looks like VB and as per your tags you can not specified language?

Comment: Are you working on SQL server or Access ?

Comment: I edited the question. The code is in Access n I have to recreate in SQL Server

Comment: @PareshJ: The Access database engine (JET) supports some expressions that have the same syntax as their VBA counterparts. `IIf` is one of them.

Comment: `I believe it checks for code not null...` Don't *believe*! Dissect and analyse the code until you *understand* what it does. Otherwise, how can you test that your new code is correct?

Comment: Checks for [code] not null or <> ABC
then length is null or 0 width is null or 0 height is null or zero
then 1 else 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal translating:

```
CASE WHEN [code] Is Not Null
THEN 
    CASE WHEN [code]<>'ABC'
    THEN
        CASE WHEN [length] Is Null 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN [Length]=0
            THEN 1
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN [width] Is Null
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN [Width]=0
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN [height] Is Null
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE
                            CASE WHEN [Height]=0
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END
    END
END
```

Simplified in :

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL([code], 'ABC') <>'ABC' AND
    (ISNULL([length], 0) = 0 OR
     ISNULL([width], 0) = 0 OR
     ISNULL([height], 0) = 0)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Brilliant , you made me understand it in very simple way :)

Answer (score 3):

`IIf` in JET SQL translates to `CASE WHEN` in SQL Server as follows:

```
IIf(condition, whenTrue, whenFalse)
```

translates directly to

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN whenTrue ELSE whenFalse END
```

For nested expressions

```
IIf(condition1, whenTrue1, IIf(condition2, whenTrue2, whenFalse))
```

you can either translate them directly:

```
CASE WHEN condition1 
     THEN whenTrue1 
     ELSE CASE WHEN condition2
               THEN whenTrue2
               ELSE whenFalse
          END
END
```

or use the fact that CASE allows you to specify multiple `WHEN` conditions:

```
CASE WHEN condition1 THEN whenTrue1 
     WHEN condition2 THEN whenTrue2
     ELSE whenFalse
END
```

With this knowledge, translating your statement should be easy and is left as an exercise to the reader (I don't want to spoil the fun).

Comment: @Lewan And when you're done translating, you can simplify with `AND`s and `OR`s, using only 1 `CASE` instead of 8 :)

Comment: 'CASE 
WHEN [code] IS NOT NULL OR [code]<>'ABC'

THEN CASE WHEN [length] Is Null OR [Length]=0 

THEN CASE WHEN [Width] Is Null OR [Width]=0

THEN CASE WHEN [Height] Is Null OR [Height]=0

THEN 1
ELSE 0

END
END
END
END'